# How to display a nice fft waterfall

Tags: python, fft, waterfall

The goal is to display a nice waterfall from an existing fft

Start from an existing fft which can be found at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
N = 600
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
yf = fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The result is the expected spectrum. Now we want to plot a waterfall as depicted at https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots
We want something like that :

```
x, y = (xf, np.arange(N))
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = yf
Axes3D.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z,rstride=1,cstride=len(xf), lw=.5, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

where X is the freq range of the Fft, Y the plot number axis and Z the 2D array with Fft data. But we get this error :

```
TypeError: plot_wireframe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Z'
```

What is the problem ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: As stated by hotpaw2, one needs Fourier transforms of sliding time windows of the data to get spectrogram of the data. You may check [spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) page of Scipy.

Answer (score 1):

To display a waterfall, you need a 2D array of FFTs (usually of different time windows), not just one FFT result.